# On probablity distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose we have some function $f(x)$ depending upon some parameters $p, n$ etc. We can show that it represents a probablity distribution function if it satisfies axioms of theory of probability. Mostly the fact that $\sum_{0}^{\infty} f(x) =1$.
Say that it's difficult to compute the summation.
Now suppose if we show that $f(x)$ tends to a wellknown distribution under a specific limit can we say that $f(x)$ is also an probablity distribution?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you mean that if $f_n(x)$ is a sequence of densities and $f_n \to f$, then $f$ is a density? And what sort of convergence are you talking about? $L^2$, pointwise, uniform?

Comment: Thank you but I have no idea what these terms mean. I will give a example. say we have the Negative Binomial distribution and we dont know whether $\sum p(x) = 1$. To show this we need to compute the summation. But it can be equivalently shown that if $p$ tends to zero, $r$ tends to infinity and $rp=m$ is finite the Negative binomial yields possion distribution which is well known and summation of probablity over all x is 1. Considering this limit can we say the NB distribution also sums to 1? For some other distribution it might be difficult to compute the summation but taking limits is easy.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you are asking. Any probability mass function of a probability distribution must sum to one by definition. Are you asking specifically for a proof of why $\sum_{k=0}^\infty {{k+r-1}\choose{k}}p^r(1-p)^k$ is equal to one?

Comment: In a statement; can the limiting case of a pmf guarantee us that $\sum p(x)=1$ ? In the example I gave earlier can the limiting case of NB which is possion guarantee us that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty {{k+r-1}\choose{k}}p^r(1-p)^k =1$. I am not asking for the proof but for a guarantee that the proof exist.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. You are asking the following: let $p_k(x)$ is a sequence of functions such that $p_k(x)\to p(x)$ for all $x$ as $k\to\infty$. Suppose $\sum_{x=0}^\infty p(x) = 1$. Then you are asking if it is true that $\sum_{x=0}^\infty p_k(x)$ = 1; do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes. I am asking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{N}_0$ denote the set of nonnegative integers $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.

Let $p(n): \mathbb{N}_0\to\mathbb{R}$ be a probability mass function, so that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n) = 1$. Let $\{p_k(n): \mathbb{N}_0\to\mathbb{R}\}$ be a sequence of functions such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} p_k(n)\to p(n)$ for all $n$. It is **not true** that each $p_k(n)$ is a probability mass function. Define
$$p(n)=\begin{cases}
1 & n = 0\\
0 & n\neq 0\end{cases}$$
and
$$p_k(n)=\begin{cases}
1-\frac{1}{k} & n = 0\\
0 & n\neq 0.\end{cases}$$
Then clearly $p(n)$ is a probability mass function and $p_k(n)\to p(n)$ for all $n$, but each $p_k(n)$ is not a probability mass function, since
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_k(n) = 1-\frac{1}{k} < 1.$$

Comment: I think you meant $1-\frac1k<1$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, corrected.